# CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE doesnt append Cookie header

Tags: php, curl

Im using MAMP on a Mac running OS X Lion.

I need to connect to a remote site sending the cookie.
All goes well except for the cookie part.
For the cookie part I'm using this code:

```
$cookieFile = dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFile); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFile);
```

The CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR part does create a cookie, but on a subsequent request CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE doesn't add a cookie header. I've checked this using HTTPScoop (a Fiddler like tool).

Any idea what might be the problem?

EDIT:
Im connecting to a ASP.Net site. Problem seems to be the im not getting a ASP.NET_SessionId cookie. The cookie i do get has a key without a value, thats probably the reason why it isn't posted.
Any idea how to force the server to send a session cookie?

Comment: `The CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR part does create a cookie` - Did you confirm that the file created actually has a cookie value in it and isn't empty?  Can you confirm from the response headers of the first request that a `Set-Cookie` header was present?

Comment: Check, the cookie gets created and the content reflects the value of the header.

Comment: I'm a bit at a loss then, are you willing to post more complete code and maybe the URL of the site you are trying to access so I could try?

Comment: If i change it to google.com it does send a cookie, so i might have to dive a little deeper in my configuration. Thanx for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'd really need to see more code, but here is a sample bit I have which collects a session cookie from an initial request then uses it in a subsequent POST.  It uses an anonymous proxy to run a GET request on an arbitrary URL, hopefully it helps you (to be clear though it doesn't use the COOKIEJAR, but I feel it may still be helpful).

```
<?php
define('TARGET_URL', 'http://moxune.com');
echo 'Sending initial request' . PHP_EOL;
$aHeaders = get_headers("http://420proxy.info");

foreach($aHeaders as $sHeader) {
    if(stripos($sHeader, 'set-cookie') !== false) {
        // extract the cookie from the first response
        $aCookie = explode(':', $sHeader);
        $sCookie = trim(array_pop($aCookie));
        $oCookie = http_parse_cookie($sCookie);

        echo 'Cookie extracted, trying to POST now' . PHP_EOL;

        // OK, now let's try the POST request
        $ch = curl_init('http://420proxy.info/includes/process.php?action=update');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, '420.proxy.info');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $sCookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect: 100-continue'));

        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, http_build_cookie((array)$oCookie));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            'u' => TARGET_URL,
            'allowCookies' => 'off',
            'encodeURL' => 'off',
            'stripJS' => 'on'
            )   
        );  

        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        die(var_dump($response));
    }   
}
```

Comment: Helpfull code, thanx. My problem was i didn't exactly mimic the posted values in my login request. After i fixed that a filled session cookie was set and posted in subsequent posts.